# Node.js undefined properties

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to create a log in window. My code is simple.

```js
var employees = {
 '1' : {
  firstName: '',
  lastName: '',
  login: 'qwerty',
  password: '12345',
 },
 '2' : {
  login: 'asdfg',
  password: '12345',
 },
};

app.post('/main', function(req, res) {
 if (!req.body) return res.sendStatus(400);
  console.log(req.body);
 for (var key in employees) {
  console.log(key['login']);
  console.log(key['password']);
  if ((key.login == req.body.login) && (key.password == req.body.password)) {
    res.render('main');
  } else {
   app.get('/', function(req,res) {
    res.send(createIndexPage());
   });
  };
 };
});
```

Why key.login and key.password return undefined?
And why else block does not run when if statement is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at what the value of `key` actually is:

```js
var employees = {
  '1': {
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    login: 'qwerty',
    password: '12345',
  },
  '2': {
    login: 'asdfg',
    password: '12345',
  },
};

for (var key in employees) {
  console.log(key);
}
```

It is the **property name** (as a string), not the value of the property.

`console.log(employees[key]['login']);` will give you what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you, it works. But why when I enter wrong data page is infinitely loading and else block does not run?